# Sitecore mvc handling multiple forms in the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

i'm using Sitecore 7, in the page that i'm currently having issues i have a layout (cshtml) with two controller renderings.

that two controller renderings is map to different controller action but using the same controller. So controller rendering A is mapped to controller "search", action "ProductSearch" and controller rendering B is mapped to controller "search", action "CustomerSearch"

The "search" controller has 4 methods in it.

1. "ProductSearch" which is returning a view result
2. "ProductSearch" with HttpPost attribute set which handle the form submission
3. "CustomerSearch" which is returning a view result
4. "CustomerSearch" with HttpPost attribute set which handle the form submission

and this is how the form is written

```
@using(Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName,FormMethod.Post))
        {             
           @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler()   
           //form fields here 
        }
```

when i submit one of the form, i notice that both of the controller actions get executed, which is not what i was expecting.

if i then change one of the controller rendering form handler to

```
@using(Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName,FormMethod.Post))
        {             
           @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("search","customersearch")   
           //form fields here 
        }
```

then only one controller action gets invoked but the page only rendered the viewresult from that controller action

is there something that i miss here?

Answer (score 0):

i found some clue from https://bitbucket.org/demoniusrex/launch-sitecore-mvc-demo/src

basically in order that Sitecore render the whole layout when doing a POST. in the controller action we need to return an ActionResult by calling the Index() - your controller need to inherit the SitecoreController.

The Index() method is responsible to render the whole layout, and initialize all the renderings and associated models. See how the model classes get initialized in the link above on how this is done.